# Concat column name in laravel where condition

Tags: laravel

I want to get a search result as the combination of two column names in the database. First column name is `ward` and its value is `2`, second column name is `cust_house_num` and its value is `123`. If my input parameter is `2123` then I want get the result row. Here is my code:

```
->Where(function($query) use ($search){
             $query->orWhere('cust_name', 'like' ,"$search%");
             $query->orWhere('cust_phone', $search);
             $query->orWhere('ward', $search);
            $query ->orWhere('CONCAT(tbl_customer.ward, " - ", tbl_customer.cust_house_num) as 
            concatname, $search');
             })
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `DB::raw` to use mysql functions:

```
->Where(function($query) use ($search){
             $query->orWhere('cust_name', 'like' ,"$search%");
             $query->orWhere('cust_phone', $search);
             $query->orWhere('ward', $search);
            $query ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(tbl_customer.ward, tbl_customer.cust_house_num)"),'like',  $search);
             })
             ->get();
```

Comment: $query ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(tbl_customer.ward, tbl_customer.cust_house_num) as 
            concatname)",'like',  $search);  this line shows error

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as 
                          concatname) is null)'

Comment: ->Where(function($query) use ($search){
                 $query->orWhere('cust_name', 'like' ,"$search%");
                 $query->orWhere('cust_phone', $search);
                 $query->orWhere('ward', $search);
               
                
                
                 $query ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(tbl_customer.ward, tbl_customer.cust_house_num) as 
                          concatname)",'like',  $search));
                 
                
             })
              
                 
                    ->get();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222476/discussion-between-buddingdeveloper-and-omr).